# Zend 1 unittest don't send POST value

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got this simple test

```
public function testUserCanRegisterAction()
   {
       $data = array(
            'email'=>'ppp@hhh.it',
            'password'=>'password',
            'repassword'=>'password',
            'domain'=>'googlish.com',
            'country'=>'it',
            'category'=>5,
            'terms_accept'=>1,
        );
        $this->request->setPost($data);
        $this->request->setHeader('X_REQUESTED_WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        $this->request->setMethod('POST');

        $this->dispatch('/user/signup');


        $body = $this->response->getBody();
        $phpNative = Zend_Json::decode($body);
        var_dump( $phpNative );

   }
```

but it seems no post values is sent
any idea about it ?

you can find more info 
https://gist.github.com/whisher

Comment: How do you check they aren't sent?

Comment: with a simple var_dump in my UserContoller, but I think I found the problem it's about tearDown() $this->request->setPost(array()); may be

Comment: I've to set it in all my test even if it sound a little strange :(

Comment: var_dump($request->getPost('email')); for instance also $request->getPost() give me a empty array